# count the elements in a list

Tags: python, list

The problem is to count the elements in a list without using len(list).

My code:

```
def countFruits(crops):
  count = 0
  for fruit in crops:
    count = count + fruit
  return count
```

The error was: 'int' and 'str'

These are supposed to be the test cases that should run the program.

```
crops = ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'banana','strawberry', 'apple']
count = countFruits(crops)
print count
7
```

Comment: In the first time through your for loop, you're asking Python to add `0` and `'apple'`.  Python doesn't know how to do this, so it throws an error.  Can you do this so you're only adding numbers together?

Comment: `count = count + 1` or  simply `count +=1`

Comment: `count = crops.__len__()`?. (unless you think that's cheating :D)

Comment: I think there's the subtle issue of when you're actually **counting** the crops vs determining the size of the list

Comment: @gnibbler The point was to *not* use `len()`, so using `__len__` instead *could* be an allowed alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def countFruits(crops):
  count = 0
  for fruit in crops:
    count = count + 1
  return count
```

To calculate the length of the list you simply have to add `1` to the counter for each element found, ignoring the `fruit`. Alternatively, you can write the line with the addition like this:

```
count += 1
```

And because we're not actually using the `fruit`, we can write the `for` like this:

```
for _ in crops:
```

Making both modifications, here's the final version of the implementation:

```
def countFruits(crops):
    count = 0
    for _ in crops:
        count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

You need simple replace wrong expression: count=count+fruit

```
def countFruits(crops):
  count = 0
  for fruit in crops:
    count += 1
  return count
```

expression for x in y, get x how object from list y, to get number you can use function enumerate(crops), return object and number.
 Other way to use:

```
countFruits = lambda x: x.index(x[-1])+1
```

but the best way is use len() you can resign name:

```
countFruits = len
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and the [Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python):

```
def count_elements(list_):
    return 1 + count_elements(list_[1:]) if list_ else 0

print(count_elements(['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'strawberry']))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: That’s very ineffective as `iterable[1:]` will continuously create new list objects causing the old ones to be thrown away (not to mention the overhead for recursion itself). Also `iterable` is the wrong term when you’re using *list* access (a list is iterable, but an iterable must not be a list).

Comment: @poke: I changed `iterable` to `list_`. I know that's not effective. Since the OP can't use `len`, I assume that this is an exercise in order to learn python programming. So I wanted to propose a way that use features that perhaps the OP didn't know about (Recursion...), and that was not already proposed.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count(x):
    return sum(1 for _ in x)
```

The above is fairly efficient; the comprehension isn't expanded into memory before taking the sum, but accumulated for each element generated.  That is to say: `sum([1 for _ in x])` would be much worse.

Can't imagine why you don't want to use `len()`...the only reason I can imagine is if the iterable is a generator and you don't want to eat the elements, in which case just add a counter to the loop (via `enumerate` makes it clean, but maybe a bit hidden.

```
for i, item in enumerate(my_generator):
     do_stuff(item)

print 'Did things to {} items'.format(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the usage of `len()` is forbidden, I assume the real meaning of the task you are given is to learn different techniques within python.

a solution using higher order function with [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) — so basically most of the python goodies…

```
def countFruits(crops):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1 for _ in crops])

crops = ['apple','orange', 'banana'] 
print countFruits(crops)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def countFruits(crops):
    return max(enumerate(crops, 1))[0]
```